# Which is better? Having 1000 clients using SSE to talk with server or Ajax polling by 1000 clients to the server

Tags: html, ajax, performance, web-services, server-sent-events

I am beginning to learn AJAX and SSE. Performance wise which method would be considered better? Assume my application will cater to 1000 clients.

1. Having Server sent events which keep 1000 http connections open for one way communication to push updates to the clients.

   or
2. Having the clients implement ajax polling for every 1 second to the server.

Comment: I'm probably not qualified to really answer this question and don't really have any evidence or reference to support my answer but I'm pretty sure the SSE route is the way to go for this.

Comment: Take a look at SignalR.

Comment: I would say this largely depends on how you expect you number of clients to scale out, what the required polling/update interval is required to be, and the frequency with which you will actually need to send a payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to have each client poke your server every 1 second. Just make the math: 1000 requests every second. As soon as one of the request starts taking more than 1 second, you will slowly start to launch a Denial of Service on your own server.

I don't know if you are in the ASP.NET environment for the server, but if you are, I suggest that you take a look at the [SignalR library](http://signalr.net/).

A typical demo app for SignalR is a chat program. See [ChatJS](http://www.chatjs.net/) or [Jabbr](http://jabbr.net).

You can [follow this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) to learn more about SignalR.

Comment: I have seen and read about signalR. Would you recommend signalR even in cases where there is no 2-way communication. Only the server will push data to the clients.

Comment: Of course, you can use the behavior of SignalR to push notification from the server to the client. For example, you want an immediate notification when a new order is placed: use signalr with a popup tool like toastr.